# Filling out empty cells based on another column

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I want to match/map the missing value in a dataframe based on another column. For example,

```
         City         State              Country
      Chicago            IL        United States
       Boston            MA        United States
    San Diego            
  Los Angeles            CA        United States
San Francisco
   Sacramento     
    Vancouver            BC               Canada
```

So, if I want to fill in the empty cells of the provinces and countries of those three cities same as Los Angeles. What should I do?

Below is my code but I'm completely stuck in it.

```
CA_cities = ['San Diego', 'Los Angeles', 'San Francisco', 'Sacramento']
df.loc[df['City'] == CA_cities, 'State' = 'CA' and 'Country' = 'United States']
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `groupby` with mask created by `isin`, then replace `NaN`s by back and forward filling:

```
CA_cities = ['San Diego', 'Los Angeles', 'San Francisco', 'Sacramento']

df = df.groupby(df['City'].isin(CA_cities)).apply(lambda x: x.ffill().bfill())
print (df)
            City State        Country
0        Chicago    IL  United States
1         Boston    MA  United States
2      San Diego    CA  United States
3    Los Angeles    CA  United States
4  San Francisco    CA  United States
5     Sacramento    CA  United States
6      Vancouver    BC         Canada
```

More general solution is create groups of cities, e.g. in dictionaries, swap `keys` wih values and `map` column:

```
print (df)
            City State        Country
0        Chicago    IL  United States
1       Chicago1   NaN            NaN
2         Boston    MA  United States
3      San Diego   NaN            NaN
4    Los Angeles    CA  United States
5  San Francisco   NaN            NaN
6     Sacramento   NaN            NaN
7      Vancouver    BC         Canada

cities = {'CA': ['San Diego', 'Los Angeles', 'San Francisco', 'Sacramento'], 
          'IL':['Chicago','Chicago1']}
d = {k: oldk for oldk, oldv in cities.items() for k in oldv}

df = df.groupby(df['City'].map(d).fillna(df['City'])).apply(lambda x: x.ffill().bfill())
#slowier alternative
#df = df.groupby(df['City'].replace(d)).apply(lambda x: x.ffill().bfill())
print (df)
            City State        Country
0        Chicago    IL  United States
1       Chicago1    IL  United States
2         Boston    MA  United States
3      San Diego    CA  United States
4    Los Angeles    CA  United States
5  San Francisco    CA  United States
6     Sacramento    CA  United States
7      Vancouver    BC         Canada
```

**Detail**:

```
print (df['City'].map(d).fillna(df['City']))
0           IL
1           IL
2       Boston
3           CA
4           CA
5           CA
6           CA
7    Vancouver
Name: City, dtype: object

print (d)
{'San Diego': 'CA', 'Los Angeles': 'CA', 'San Francisco': 'CA', 
 'Sacramento': 'CA', 'Chicago': 'IL', 'Chicago1': 'IL'}
```

Comment: Thank you for providing more than one methods. And it's well-explained. Appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

Or just split it , and using `fillna`.

```
CA_cities = ['SanDiego', 'LosAngeles', 'SanFrancisco', 'Sacramento']
s=df.loc[df.City.isin(CA_cities),:]
t=df.loc[~df.City.isin(CA_cities),:]
pd.concat([s.fillna({'State':'CA','Country':'UnitedStates'}),t])
Out[1023]: 
           City State       Country
2      SanDiego    CA  UnitedStates
3    LosAngeles    CA  UnitedStates
4  SanFrancisco    CA  UnitedStates
5    Sacramento    CA  UnitedStates
0       Chicago    IL  UnitedStates
1        Boston    MA  UnitedStates
6     Vancouver    BC        Canada
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution. Appreciated!